# Issue injecting angular-ui into my controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have ui.bootstrap as a dependency in my app, but I'm having an issue injecting the $modal service into my controller.
I'm getting the following error:

```
   $modal is not defined
```

in my controller code, specifically in this function below where I attempt to open a modal :

```
 function saveAndDisplayReport() {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
        $location.url('index.html#/?reptname=' + vm.reptName);
    }
```

Here's my reportmaint.js controller code header section, but Im' unclear on how to inject ui.bootstrap (please see the $modal parameter):

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'reportmaint';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'common',  'datacontext',
                                                'gridHierarchyService', 'reportsContext', '$modal', reportmaint]);

function reportmaint($rootScope, $scope, $location, common, datacontext, gridHierarchyService, reportsContext) {
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);        
    var logErr = getLogFn("error");
  ...
 })();
```

and here is my app.js where 'ui.bootstrap' is defined:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', [
    // Angular modules 
    'ngAnimate',        // animations
    'ngRoute',          // routing
    'ngSanitize',       // sanitizes html bindings (ex: sidebar.js)

    // Custom modules 
    'common',           // common functions, logger, spinner
    'common.bootstrap', // bootstrap dialog wrapper functions

    // 3rd Party Modules
    'ui.bootstrap',          // ui-bootstrap (ex: carousel, pagination, dialog)
    'kendo.directives',      // Kendo UI
    'app.customcontrollers' // Language/Currency settings        
    //'ngjqxsettings'      // jQWidgets init and directives (loaded in index.html)
]);
app.run(['$route', '$rootScope', 'common', 'userService', function ($route, $rootScope, common, userService) {
  console.log("In app.run");
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn('app');

 }]);
```

})();

and in my index.html file I have the script reference :

```
  <script src="scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
```

I am using this plunker as a live example, but I'm still going wrong somewhere - http://plnkr.co/edit/KsADLPaOfY7rtPTdWyYn?p=preview

thanks in advance for your help...

Bob

Comment: the plunkr link is wrong

Comment: I fixed the plunker URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like you are not injecting the modal at all ($modal is missing) in the function of your controller; try something like:

I'm not sure if reportmaint is a service, if not, just remove it

```
angular.module('app').controller('reportmaint', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'common',  'datacontext','gridHierarchyService', 'reportsContext', '$modal', 'reportmaint',
    function($rootScope, $scope, $location, common, datacontext, gridHierarchyService, reportsContext, $modal, reportmaint) {
        //Client code

    }
]);
```

Comment: now I'd like to simply call it in my saveAndDisplayReport() function.

Comment: create your function using $scope call it from a button using ng-click! cheers!

Comment: what's weird now is that even though I can invoke the modal window via javascript, it doesn't actually stop processing due to the promises it returns. I would like to actually stop to prompt the user, as in var resp = vm.open('sm'). PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Post another question with your new case